# How do I run the Initial value x0 also in parallel

Tags: matlab, quantum-computing

This code works fine but the plot is not correct because the optimization function `fmincon` will depend on the initial condition `x0` and the number of iterations. For each value of alpha (`a`) and beta (`b`), I should run the optimization many times with different initial conditions `x0` to verify that I am getting the right answer. More iterations might be required to get an accurate answer.

I want to be able to run the optimization with different initial conditions for `x0`, `a` and `b`.

Function file

```
function f = threestate2(x,a,b)
c1 = cos(x(1))*(cos(x(5))*(cos(x(9))+cos(x(11)))+cos(x(7))*(cos(x(9))-cos(x(11))))...
   +cos(x(3))*(cos(x(5))*(cos(x(9))-cos(x(11)))-cos(x(7))*(cos(x(9))+cos(x(11))));
c2=sin(x(1))*(sin(x(5))*(sin(x(9))*cos(x(2)+x(6)+x(10))+sin(x(11))*cos(x(2)+x(6)+x(12)))...
    +sin(x(7))*(sin(x(9))*cos(x(2)+x(8)+x(10))-sin(x(11))*cos(x(2)+x(8)+x(12))))...
    +sin(x(3))*(sin(x(5))*(sin(x(9))*cos(x(4)+x(6)+x(10))-sin(x(11))*cos(x(4)+x(6)+x(12)))...
    -sin(x(7))*(sin(x(9))*cos(x(4)+x(8)+x(10))+sin(x(11))*cos(x(4)+x(8)+x(12))));
f=(a*a-b*b)*c1+2*a*b*c2;
```

Main file

```
%x=[x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12)]; % angles;

lb=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
ub=[pi,2*pi,pi,2*pi,pi,2*pi,pi,2*pi,pi,2*pi,pi,2*pi];
x0=[pi/8;0;pi/3;0;0.7*pi;.6;0;pi/2;.5;0;pi/4;0];
xout=[];
fout=[];
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point','TolX',10^-10,'MaxIter',1500);
a=0:0.01:1;
w=NaN(length(a));

for i=1:length(a)
     bhelp=(1-a(i)*a(i));
if bhelp>0
    b=sqrt(bhelp);
       [x,fval]=fmincon(@(x)threestate2(x,a(i),b),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
w(i)=fval;
w(i)=-w(i);
B(i)=b;
else
w(i)=NaN;
B(i)=b;
end 
end
%surface(b,a,w)
%view(3)
%meshc(b,a,w)
x=a.^2;
plot(x,w)
grid on
ylabel('\fontname{Times New Roman} S_{max}(\Psi_{gs})')
xlabel('\fontname{Times New Roman}\alpha^2')
%ylabel('\fontname{Times New Roman}\beta')
title('\fontname{Times New Roman} Maximum of the Svetlichny operator(\alpha|000>+\beta|111>)')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Matlab Parallel Toolbox, you can use the [parfor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) which is like a regular loop but runs in parallel.

To use it you should make your all big messy script in a function. Assuming you store your initial conditions in `A(i)` and you store the results in `B(i)` you can use something like that:

```
parfor i=1:length(B)
    B(i)=optimise(A(i));
end
```

If you don't have the toolbox there are some other ways (for example MEX files) but you basically have to manage the threads yourself so I wouldn't recommend it.